# C++ Does inlining a namespace implicitly inline its functions?

Tags: c++, namespaces, inline

If I have a header with:

```
namespace outer {
    inline namespace inner {
        void func();
    }
}
```

Then I can't define `func()` in a seperate .cpp file as that gives me a compile error:

`- undefined reference to 'outer::inner::func()'`

Just as if I declared the function inline. Is this correct? Does this mean that inlining a namespace implicitly inlines its functions. I tried looking at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace but couldn't find anywhere that this is explicitly stated.

EDIT 2:
Disregard, previous edit. I had failed to configue my cmake file properly and therefore was unable to compile the code. See answer for answer to original question. Thanks everyone!

<s>EDIT:</s>

Here is an example that I am unable to compile:

Test.h

```
namespace Core {
    inline namespace TestNameSpace {
        void write();
    }
}
```

Test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Test.h"

void Core::write() {
    std::cout << "BAJS\n";
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"
int main() {
    Core::write();
    return 0;
}
```

I should note, `#include "Test.h"` is grayed out in my IDE in the Test.cpp file.

Comment: I think the problem is in how you are compiling.

Comment: Ok, so the example above should in theory work then? And I have some other issue, correct?

Comment: Could not reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/N7fDhz

Comment: Added edit with example.

Comment: But the compiler output does not match the functions? There's potentially a good question here - needs another edit.

Comment: If I understand inline namespaces correctly, your problem is with you referring to the `::inner` namespace in the first place -- it should just be `outer::func`.  Inner namespaces appear in the mangled name, but are not referred to in the source.  They seem to be an ABI compatibility mechanism more than anything else.

Comment: @ChuckAdams, both `outer::inner::func()` and `outer::func()` are valid.

Comment: users interested in the edit history can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59990596/revisions). You do not have to clutter your question with no longer relevant edits. Imho also putting a "EDIT:" header is unnecessary, because the question should be understandable in their current state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is: no. You can absolutely define the functions in a separate cpp file. `inline` on a namespace basically makes it so that you don't need to specify the namespace name. For example, you can do `outer::func()` instead of `outer::inner::func()`

See [`[namespace.def]/5-7`](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.def#5). There is no restrictions on where you must define the functions, and that it implicitly inlines them.

The error you are getting is in how you are compiling. Likely, you forgot to compile the .cpp file, or at least link it to where it is being called from.

Comment: do you know when the possibility to declare a namespace as `inline` was added? In my favorite c++ reference I could not find a single word about inline namespaces

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Since C++11. Quite surprising if a reference doesn't mention it.

Comment: uh it was all my fault, i was reading [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) when I should have consulted [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) instead.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Right, for a namespace it is not really a specifier, so it doesn't belong on the "inline specifier" page. Really `inline` namespaces have nothing to do at all with the meaning of `inline` in the `inline` specifier. I guess they just wanted to reuse a keyword instead of introducing a new one.

Comment: Thanks! The reason it didn't compile in my project was that I had forgot to configure my cmake file correctly.